# Random node in an Erdos Renyi network

Tags: python, random, networkx

I'm new to networkx, and I want to extract a random node from the erdos_renyi graph, I'm using this code, but I get an empty list

```
N = 1000 
p = 0.01 
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(N, p)
node = list(random.choice(G.nodes()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just a little bit off on your calling sequence:

```
node = list(random.choice(G.nodes()))
```

`G.nodes()` is a node view of the graph; you need a list of nodes, `G.nodes`

```
node = [ random.choice(list(G.nodes)) ]
```

Turn the node view into a list, grab a random element form that, and then stuff it into a list (I'm not sure why you wanted a list of one element).

Comment: I still get an empty list

Comment: Yes, you did -- my mistake.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the nodes in the graph are integers from 0 to 999, you can also directly use [`random.randrange(N)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to get a random node.
On an arbitrary graph, you can do the same after calling [`convert_node_labels_to_integers`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html#networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers).

```
import networkx as nx
import random

N = 1000
p = 0.01
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(N, p)
print(G.nodes())
# prints 0 to N - 1

node = [random.randrange(N)]
```